# Can I backup my iPhone without Wi-Fi?

Tags: ios, itunes, backup

I have iPhone 6. Can I back it up without WiFi? Is there any other way? I do not have access to WiFi.

Comment: Some one said there is another way to back up your stuff without WiFi is this possible ??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You can back it up to iTunes on your computer and there's many answers on this site already that help with that.  Additionally, there's hundreds of guides on the internet that can show you step-by-step.  What have you already tried and what errors, if any, did you get?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac with iTunes you can connect your iPhone to your computer with a USB/Lightning cable and then back up your iPhone to iTunes on your computer. I've done this many times with my iPhone 6 and my older iMac.

Comment: In fact, before there was backup with Wi-Fi, using the USB cable was the only method.